# Getting centroid of multipart polygon using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, multipart, multi-polygon

I am trying to get the center of a multipolygon, I have tried doing:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        multipoly = row[0]
        centroid = multipoly.centroid
```

The feature class is using WGS84 coordinates.

This only seems to grab the centroid of only one of the parts. Ideally, I would like to get the center point of all the parts in the multipolygon.

Any suggestions for approaches I can pursue?

Comment: You need to iterate through the parts to generate a label for each.

Comment: Look at the example at the bottom of the page. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/reading-geometries.htm